# rpc server C++ Linux server and Windows client

Tags: c++, linux, windows, rpc, protocol-buffers

Is there a nice implementation of an RPC server that runs on Linux and has a client for Windows.
It should use protcolbuf for messages.
All code is C++.

The only examples I can find all compile well on Linux but do not have so much luck on Windows!

I checked  all these https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns

Answer (score 0):

What about [Mongrel2](http://mongrel2.org/) and [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)?

You can, in fact, write handlers in what ever language you want.